# How to Pass Input Value in Form to URL (Sub Domain)

Tags: php, forms

Situation:
The form is at https://example.com
If user write "demo" in input then submit, they will be redirected to
https://demo.example.com where "demo" is from the value they've putted before.

How to do that?

My code:

```html
<form class="form-inline" action="http://example.com" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Login</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">https://</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="username" value="">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.example.com</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is ok for you, here is a simple solution:

```
$(function() {

    $('#form').submit(function() {

        var subdomain = $('#exampleInputAmount').val();
        $('#form').attr('action', 'http://' + subdomain + '.example.com');

        return true;
    });

});
```

Comment: I put this inside script tag just before body closing. It's does't work. I don't know why. :)

Comment: Did you add jQuery to page? (e.g. into head `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>`). Does javascript console throw some error?

Comment: @Syafiq Zainal, you have also to put id="form" to your form attributes

Answer (score 1):

After button clicked the form will be submitted. So on the top of page you may use below code.

**PHP Solution:**

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $text = $_GET['inputtext'];
    $url = 'http://'.$text.'example.com';
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
}
```

HTML Change:

```
<input type="text" name="inputtext" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="username" value="">
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

Comment: This works for redirection, but this way you will lose all other POST/GET form data after directing to subdomain, and if the need is to authenticate this is not the best :)

Comment: Right, it is not clear. @Syafiq Zainal, will you perform authentication after redirecting to subdomain.example.com?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not very clear. But i just need the form to redirect to that url without any authentication. :)

Comment: An error in this line. I have no idea what's wrong.. Thank you for your answer. :)

`$url = http://$text."example.com";`